# Having trouble resetting staging and committed area

Tags: git

I would like to be able to do the following things on git terminal:

1. View all changes in the staging area.
2. View all committed changes.
3. Reset all committed Changes
4. Reset all staging area changes.

I have not been able to find a clear example online of how to do this.

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question. I suggest you reach out to your instructor or TA if you need help. Otherwise, Google each of the questions and see what you can find. (The first one gives the answer in the first hit.) For more indepth understanding, check out [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Answer (score 0):

- View all changes in the staging area

This is easy: `git diff --cached`. When `git diff` show difference between working directory and current branch, `--cached` show the differences between staging area and current branch.

- View all committed changes

This is not clear. I think you want to see latest commit. You can see the commit diff using `git show <commit hash>`

- Reset all committed Changes

Whenever I want to reset last commit I run `git reset HEAD~1`. This remove last commit, but the file changes will stay in your working tree.

- Reset all staging area changes

To reset all staging area the command just run `git reset` and all files in staging area will be removed from that location to working directory.